# Abnormal tabbar behavior when an UIAlertView is shown with iOS 7 - application skips to last tab automatically when the alert is dismissed

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview

I am showing an `UIAlertView` in iOS application from Xcode 5. it is a tabbed application. The `UIAlertView` is shown on the default tab (first tab) and when the alertview is dismissed, the application automatically skip to the third tab.

code for UIAlertView is:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
    if (granted) {
        // Microphone enabled code

    }

    else {
        // Microphone disabled code
        recordButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        microPhoneAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Microphone is Turned Off" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [microPhoneAlert show];
    }
}];
```

and is written in viwDidLoad.

and the delegate method is:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
      { 
         if(alertView == microPhoneAlert) 
             { 
              } 
       }
```

Can anyone tell why it behaves like that ?

thanks . . . :)

Comment: post code of UIAlertView please

Comment: code posted on the question

Comment: @specios you set the class instance as the delegate, could you post the UIAlertViewDelegate implementation for a sanity check?

Comment: @John There is nothing with the UIAlertViewDelegate implementation . . . I just added the method  -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex   thats it . . .

Comment: @specios show this method please

Comment: -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 
    if(alertView == microPhoneAlert)
    {
    
    }
}

Comment: @specios avoid putting code in the comments section (that's what the question portion is for). Is there anywhere in your project where you need to switch tabs programmatically?

Comment: No, no need to switch tabs programmatically . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved . . . It is fine when I set the delegate to nil as:

```
recordButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    microPhoneAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Microphone is Turned Off" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [microPhoneAlert show];
```

Comment: delegate:self is changed to delegate:nil